# Is it possible to prevent Firebase's onDataChange() from being triggered initially?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to make onDataChange() not be triggered just as you set the listener and instead only when the actual data changes?

Comment: Do you mean so that if you have preexisting data in your Firebase database it won't download that data and only download data that's been stored since you initialized the Firebase listener?

Comment: A `ValueEventListener` is defined as being called for the current value and every change to that value. There is no way to change that behavior. This sounds like a[ XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though: what use-case are you trying to implement that makes you want to not receive the initial value?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Consider an example of an App fetching the data and populating list from its own endpoint backed by its own master db(which is in sync with firebase db) and then once the changes are done to that data listen to onChild** events of firebase and update the list..Is that possible?Any idea how can we ignore initial onChildAdded() events of firebase db and only fetch the data from our endpoint at first attempt?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible the way you want. the firebase listener starts just after you are authenticated and an eventlistener is setup .